# Восстановление поврежденного файла Excel после неудачного сохранения через Pandas Python

Tags: pandas, excel, xlsx, восстановление

Файл с расширением .xlsx поврежден.
Он был сохранен с использованием библиотеки python pandas, и код был прерван, в результате файл был поврежден. Автосохранение отключено. Любые попытки восстановления через офисное ПО или дополнительные онлайн-утилиты тщетны.
Файл можно попытаться открыть поменяв расширение на .csv, но восстановить в нем кодировку никак не получается.
Какие еще есть варианты решения проблемы? Могу сбросить файл для тестов. Изображение с неправильной кодировкой: [изображение] [1]

Comment: Так файл по сути текстовый (csv) или бинарный упакованный (xlsx)? Если текстовый, то угадать кодировку довольно просто. А запоротый бинарник нереально восстановить.

Comment: скорее всего, как ты говоришь, что запоротый бинарник. потому что кодировку я не могу вообще подобрать.

Comment: Ну, хорошо бы файл посмотреть. Картинка не прикрепилась